# Entlib validation to syntax to accept only numeric month numbers?

Tags: validation, enums, integer, enterprise-library

I've got an enum defined as such:

```
Private Enum AllowedMonthNumbers
    _1
    _2
    _3
    _4
    _5
    _6
    _7
    _8
    _9
    _10
    _11
    _12
End Enum
```

Then a property validator defined as:

```
<TypeConversionValidator(GetType(Int32), MessageTemplate:="Card expiry month must be numeric.", Ruleset:="CreditCard")> _
<EnumConversionValidator(GetType(AllowedMonthNumbers), MessageTemplate:="Card expiry month must be between 1 and 12.", Ruleset:="CreditCard")> _
```

The validation expects "_#", as when I remove the TypeConversionValidator, it passes with setting the value to "_3" or any other number in the enum.

What I need is for this to only accept b/t 1-12, and simply having numeric values in the enum won't work.

Any tips?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

I replaced the EnumConversionValidator with a RangeValidator, and attempting to set the parameter to "1", but received the following error:

```
<RangeValidator(1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 12, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, MessageTemplate:="...">
```

However that's now giving me the following error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentException: Object must be of type Int32.
   at System.Int32.CompareTo(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RangeChecker`1.IsInRange(T target)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RangeValidator`1.DoValidate(T objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validator`1.DoValidate(Object objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.AndCompositeValidator.DoValidate(Object objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.ValueAccessValidator.DoValidate(Object objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.AndCompositeValidator.DoValidate(Object objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.GenericValidatorWrapper`1.DoValidate(T objectToValidate, Object currentTarget, String key, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validator`1.Validate(T target, ValidationResults validationResults)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validation.Validate[T](T target, String[] rulesets)
   at ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RangeValidator` can only handle primitive types such as int, float, double, decimal. Because you supply an integer in the constructor it is trying to match that int to your enum, which will fail, because VAB uses the `Object.Compare(object)` method.

Try using a design where you don't have to define a number range as enum. Try using a simple integer field instead. Much less painful.